# How can I connect to a hard coded IP address using http in iOS 12+

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to make a simple prototype with both a server (EC2 dev server) and a client. Where the server just has a hard IPv4 address (numbers) and send http results upon requests and the client is a prototype iOS 12+ app where I simply want to retrieve data from the server that is using http. How can I do so? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read up on [URLSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession) and how to [fetch webside data into memory](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/fetching_website_data_into_memory).

```
func startLoad() {
let url = URL(string: "http://IPADDRESS/")!
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
    if let error = error {
        self.handleClientError(error)
        return
    }
    guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
        (200...299).contains(httpResponse.statusCode) else {
        self.handleServerError(response)
        return
    }
    // Data is in the data-variable.
    if let mimeType = httpResponse.mimeType, mimeType == "text/html",
        let data = data,
        let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
        // Avoid using the main-thread to return any data.
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // Return data to use in view/viewcontroller
            self.webView.loadHTMLString(string, baseURL: url)
        }
    }
}
task.resume()
```

}

Other things you probably will want to get into is [MVVM/MVC](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/what-is-mvvm) for managing data between views and [Codables](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types).

Comment: Thank you! you are a life saver! and thanks for the further reading!

Comment: MVVM/MVC, is key to this question LOL